# Compare List<String> to Flux<String> in non blocking way

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

How to compare List to Flux in non blocking way

Below the code in blocking way

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> all = List.of("A", "B", "C", "D");

        Flux<String> valid = Flux.just("A", "D");

        Map<Boolean, List<String>> collect = all.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> valid.collectList().block().contains(t)));

        System.out.println(collect.get(Boolean.TRUE));
        System.out.println(collect.get(Boolean.FALSE));
    }
```

how to get it working in non-blocking way?
Above is an example of what i am trying to do in web application. I receive list of object which is List all. Then i query database which return Flux . Flux returned by database will be subset of List all. I need to prepare two lists. List of items which are present in Flux of valid and List of items which are not present in Flux of valid

EDIT:
I converted Flux to Mono and List to Mono,

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Mono<List<String>> all = Mono.just(List.of("A", "B", "C", "D"));

    Mono<List<String>> valid = Mono.just(List.of("A", "D"));


    var exist = all.flatMap(a -> valid.map(v -> a.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v::contains))));

    System.out.println(exist.block().get(Boolean.TRUE));
    System.out.println(exist.block().get(Boolean.FALSE));
}
```

Comment: HOw do you know what the flux is done

Comment: do you mean how do i know what is in flux? I know flux will be subset of List all.

Comment: When will it be that?

Comment: I have updated my question with more description

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way of achieve this in reactive programming without breaking some of its semantics.

If you reflect back on what reactive programming tris to achieve and your problem statement, you should notice that those won't play well that much together.

Reactive programming, as the name suggests, is about reacting to events which in your case would be `valid` items emitted from your datastore. In a typical situation, you should have been programming your statement to compute some assertions around the emitted `valid` items then emit these (or some other transformations downstream). Unfortunately, you won't be able to compute the `all` and `valid` items intersection and diversion without *stopping* at some point (otherwise how would you know that an item you assumed non-valid is not emitted at some point by the `valid` publisher).

Though, to achieve the desired behavior, you will lean on memory to buffer items then trigger your validations.

Retrieving valid items should be achievable using the `filterWhen` operator paired with the `hasElement` one:

```
Flux<String> validItems = Flux.fromIterable(all)
            .filterWhen(valid::hasElement);
```

To retrieve the invalid items, you can collect `all` and `validItems` `merge`d together then filter out elements that do appear more than once:

```
Flux<String> inValidItems = Flux.fromIterable(all)
            .mergeWith(validItems)
            .collectList()
            .flatMapIterable(list -> list.stream().filter(item -> Collections.frequency(list, item) == 1).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: I updated my question with another i fixed without blocking. Would appreciate if you can comment on my approach